# Is DD4T adopted in many projects?

Tags: dd4t

I am going to use DD4T in my current project, but my customer is concerned about the number of implementations and the stability. These are seen as important.

How many projects are using DD4T?

Comment: FYI... Tridion has now included DD4T in its reference implemenation. Here are a couple of links: http://www.joles.me/2015/02/13/the-digital-experience-accelerator-dxa/ http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/reference_implementation.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes. I don't have a definitive count, but as far as I know there are more implementations running now that use DD4T then those that do not. Personally, i haven't implemented anything but DD4T since it came out.

Comment: Thank you. I think so, because there were some DD4T sessions at SDL Innovate 2015 at San Francisco and there are many questions about DD4T in this community.

Answer (score 3):

As of writing there are 201 questions tagged with [dd4t](/questions/tagged/dd4t) (roughly 6% of the 3204 questions on this site). I think this speaks for itself in terms of an indicator of adoption of DD4T as a delivery framework for Tridion based web applications.